# git clone - how to keep .git in folder name by default

Tags: git

From man git-clone:

```
   <directory>
       The name of a new directory to clone into. The "humanish" part of the source repository
       is used if no directory is explicitly given (repo for /path/to/repo.git and foo for
       host.xz:foo/.git). Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is
       empty.
```

I want to have my git-clone make apparently non-humanish folders named "project.git" by default. How?

edit: Should've probably specified, --bare repo is not the clone goal here.

Comment: Why don't you want to supply the directory-name argument explicitly, e.g., `git clone $URL repo.git`?

Comment: Because after 1000 times of doing that one (or at least I) can't help but think "wasn't this what computers were made for". Also it's much too annoying in the case of super-duper-cool-seitsmepenikoormasaapad-project.git and will require way too much attention and/or mouse for such a simplistic thing to be accomplished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need external scripts to wrap this! This is exactly what git aliases are for, e.g. I have an alias called `clonez`. Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    clonez = "!sh -c 'git clone $1 ${1##*/}' -"
```

Usage:

```
git clonez git://github.com/till/jsonlint.git
```

Done. Creates a local folder `jsonlint.git`.

Comment: :) who were the meanies downvoting the script approach? Yep aliases is definitely good stuff as well, shouldn't Usage be "git clonez <url>" though?

Comment: Works nicely. While setting this up, I ran into an interesting phenom of git aliases not working because of broken or unreadable directories in PATH. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=53) is discussion and fix info.

Comment: There's an issue with the clonez alias. If I do clonez in an existing git repo, the clone target seems to be placed into root directory of the repo, not $PWD.

Comment: Solved with $GIT_PREFIX since 1.7.6, answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new script in your execution path called git-myclone (or whatever you want).  In it, create a script that matches the last pattern of the URL and adds the required repository directory based on a regexp match of the URL.  IE, something close to (but I'll let you tailor it for yourself):

```
#!/bin/sh

url=$1
dir=$2

if [ "$2" = "" ] ; then
    dir=`echo "$url" | sed 's#.*/##'`.git
fi

git clone $url $dir
```

Then 'git myclone URL' should work as you want.

Comment: Good thinking! Looks like something that would fit well in https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras. I guess this means there is no builtin git config variable that I've missed..

Comment: See my answer, this is not necessary.

Comment: See my head: I'm aware of aliases!  I actually considered mentioning it, and in hind sight I should have mentioned both answers.  You're right about that.  However, I tend to prefer scripts since the above would have been bound to grow and scripts are easier to manage and maintain in a (git controlled) directory.  But, that's an opinion not a fact of course.  Thanks for the down vote!

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --mirror <url-path>
git clone --bare <url-path>
```

Will preserve or append the .git suffix, as it is the default naming convention for bare repositories.